# How to change the increment or step or scale of a Google Benchmark 'Range()' function

Tags: c++, parameters, benchmarking, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I have a very simple Google Benchmark program that benchmarks a function taking two integer arguments, I'm trying to use the benchmark to see how exactly does the time the function takes increase as the second argument's value increases from `1` to `100`, so with the first argument staying with the same value of `999999` .

The way to achieve this that looked the most logical to me was to use Google Benchmark's `Ranges()` function like this:

```
// registering function 'largestDivisorOdd' as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(largestDivisorOdd) ->Ranges( { {999999, 999999}, {1,100} } );
```

The resulting output was this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                             Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
largestDivisorOdd/999999/1          116 ns          116 ns      6018141
largestDivisorOdd/999999/8          205 ns          205 ns      3485489
largestDivisorOdd/999999/64        2715 ns         2715 ns       260611
largestDivisorOdd/999999/100       2710 ns         2710 ns       256160
```

My problem is that it seems Google Benchmark has made the range from only values of an exponential increase from  `1` to `100`, resulting in only 4 benchmarks of 4 different values for the second parameter, instead of 100 benchmarks of 100 values from `1` to `100` as I expected and wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the following should work:

```
BENCHMARK(largestDivisorOdd)
    ->ArgsProduct({
      benchmark::CreateRange(999999, 999999, /*multi=*/2), // This is probably not what you want
      benchmark::CreateDenseRange(1, 100, /*step=*/1) // This creates a DenseRange from 1 to 100
    })
```

Or create your own custom arguments:

```
static void CustomArguments(benchmark::internal::Benchmark* b) {
  for (int i = 999999; i <= 999999; ++i)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
      b->Args({i, j});
}
BENCHMARK(BM_SetInsert)->Apply(CustomArguments);
```

Both examples are taken from the [User Guide](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#passing-arguments)